# Excel Macro issue - Run-time Error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me to fix this issue?? Iam getting the error "**Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object' _Worksheet' failed**" in the last line... Also let me know if there is any other way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance...

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("data.xlsx").Worksheets("Export")
set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceData")

wsCopy.UsedRange.AutoFilter 37, Criteria1:=Array("1/0/1990 12:00:00 AM"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

wsCopy.Range("A2:AJ2" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A2:AJ2")
```

Getting error in the last line...

Comment: `"A2:AJ2" & CopyLastRow` if your last row is 10 then it will try and copy `A2:AJ210` into the range `A2:AJ2` which won't fit.

Comment: Could you please help me to fix this??

Comment: I'm assuming you've got headers on row 1 which you don't want to include.  Try `wsCopy.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(wsCopy.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Copy wsDest.Range("A2")` - remove `Offset(1).Resize(wsCopy.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)` if you want to include the headers.

Comment: I did some changes to my original code and its working. I have posted the answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes and the below code is working...

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("data.xlsx").Worksheets("Export")
set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceData")

wsCopy.UsedRange.AutoFilter 37, Criteria1:=Array("1/0/1990 12:00:00 AM"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

wsCopy.Range("A2:AJ" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A2")
```